# Why am I getting Error 1054: Unknown column in field list for certain inputs?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I've been getting unknown column error even though the field exists in the table 'WebsiteRole':

**ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'role' in 'field list'**

Now after some research, I understand that it could be because of the trigger that's set up on this table. I checked the code of the trigger and it's still not apparent to me as to what's wrong in its code.

What's weird is the insert works for input combinations where role is not 'editor'.

Here are the tables:
[image: WebsiteRole]
[image]

Here's my input trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`vasisht54`@`%` TRIGGER `website_server`.`WebsiteRole_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `WebsiteRole` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE var_role varchar(15);
SET var_role = NEW.role;
IF var_role = 'owner' THEN
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'create', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'read', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'update', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'delete', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
ELSEIF var_role = 'admin' THEN
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'create', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'read', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'update', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'delete', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
ELSEIF role = 'writer' THEN
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'create', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'read', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'update', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
ELSEIF var_role = 'editor' THEN
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'read', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'update', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
ELSEIF var_role = 'reviewer' THEN
    INSERT INTO WebsitePriviledge VALUES(NULL, 'read', NEW.dev_id,NEW.website_id);
END IF;
END
```

Here's the error message that I'm getting for inputs where the role is 'editor'
[image: Error message]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug!

The variable I've declared in the trigger is **var_role**. Typo in the *if* condition check for 'writer' where I've written **role** as the variable instead of **var_role**..ffs